# Twig Bridge Syntax for Route

Tags: laravel-5, twig

This is a valid Laravel route:

```
{{ url: (route('admin.surveys.groups.questions.store', [survey.id, group.id])) }}
```

I can display this in a `.twig` file. How do I use it in a `form_open()`?

I've tried;

```
{{ form_open(route('admin.surveys.groups.questions.store', [survey.id, group.id])) }}

{{ form_open(url: route('admin.surveys.groups.questions.store', [survey.id, group.id])) }}

{{ form_open(url: [route('admin.surveys.groups.questions.store', [survey.id, group.id])]) }}
```

Just any combination really. It's very frustrating. [The docs clearly say it works with `route`](https://github.com/rcrowe/TwigBridge#functionsfiltersvariables) but I can't figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

`FormBuilder#open()` has only one argument: An array of `$options`. So first things first, pass an array:

```
{{ form_open({}) }}
```

Now, what's the name of the option you want to set? I guess the `action` option. Let's do that:

```
{{ form_open({ action: '...' }) }}
```

Now, what value do we set it to? The route `route('admin.surveys.groups.questions.store', [survey.id, group.id])`:

```
{{ form_open({ action: route('admin.surveys.groups.questions.store', [survey.id, group.id])) }) }}
```

Comment: No, that still produces an error... Here is my code; `{{ form_open({ action: route('admin.surveys.groups.questions.store', [survey.id, group.id]) }) }}`.

Comment: this is it..; `{{ form_open({route: ['admin.surveys.groups.questions.update', survey.id, group.id, question.id]}) }}`. you pointed me in the right direction though with the FormBuilder class